# Simple Debug during tests

Tags: solidity, testing

I'm new in solidity and I'd like to have a little bit of debug.

this is my simple example (I'm using web3 1.0)

I have a simple function in my contract

```
function bar(address _address_usr) public  {
        uint res = 5;
        emit foo('test',res);       
    }
```

And I have test about it

```
.....
it("...", async () => {

        let livello = await instance.methods.bar(accounts[0]).call();


        instance.events.foo(function (error, event) {
            console.log(event);
        })
            .on('data', function (event) {
                console.log("OK");
                console.log(event); 
            })
            .on('changed', function (event) {
                console.log("OK");
            })
            .on('error', console.error);    

    });
....
```

I'd like to know the result of res.
I tried with event but I have this error

> ```
> err Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider
> ```

Can I print some result/var in my console like console.log or something like that?

Thanks

> UPDATE

My web3 istance

helpers.js

```
const Web3 = require("web3") // import web3 v1.0 constructor

// use globally injected web3 to find the currentProvider and wrap with web3 v1.0
const getWeb3 = () => {
    const myWeb3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
    return myWeb3
}

// assumes passed-in web3 is v1.0 and creates a function to receive contract name
const getContractInstance = (web3) => (contractName) => {
    const artifact = artifacts.require(contractName) // globally injected artifacts helper
    const deployedAddress = artifact.networks[artifact.network_id].address
    const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(artifact.abi, deployedAddress)
    return instance
}

module.exports = { getWeb3, getContractInstance }
```

my test.js

```
const {getWeb3, getContractInstance} = require("./helpers")
const web3 = getWeb3()
const getInstance = getContractInstance(web3)
```

Comment: I recommend looking at how open zeppelin implement tests, they have helper functions to parse events, https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/test/helpers/expectEvent.js, but honestly I miss the old way they did things :P.

Comment: Try to share the code where you create the web3 instance, I think you might be using websocket functionality and that's where it's failing, to catch the error, do a try catch when generating the instance, to fix the problem don't use ws, or use a web socket compatible node

Comment: @EnriqueAlcazar I updated my question. the only way to read variable inside my code is events?

Comment: If you want to debug, you can use remix, they have a pretty good debugger, also remember that you can use strings as a second parameter to your reverts, and you can create constant functions (views) to read any parameter in your blockchain

Comment: Check that web3 you are using is correct, IE: console.log it and look if the params are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error states that you are using `HttpProvider` for web3 and as per the web3 documentation [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#value), it states:

> Object - HttpProvider: The HTTP provider is deprecated, as it won’t
>   work for subscriptions.

and this error is appearing from this [code](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/packages/web3-core-subscriptions/src/subscription.js):

```
// throw error, if provider doesnt support subscriptions
    if(!this.options.requestManager.provider.on) {
        var err2 = new Error('The current provider doesn\'t support subscriptions: '+ this.options.requestManager.provider.constructor.name);
        this.callback(err2, null, this);
        this.emit('error', err2);
        return this;
    }
```

I think for event subscription you should try to use other alternatives of provider.

**UPDATE:**
To get the value of event parameters you can change the code like this:

```
   it("...", async () => {

            let livello = await instance.methods.bar(accounts[0]).send();
            console.log(livello.events.foo.returnValues);
}
```

This will print the event params values. For more, visit: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

Furthermore, if you are looking to print the variables value only, you should rather use view/pure function without events. For more info, visit: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/contracts.html#functions

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Are you looking to get the values of event variables from transaction?

Comment: I'd like to have a method to debug my contract I want to get the val of res for istance,
Event is a good approach?

Comment: remove `.call()` from your function call and you will get it in event params.

Comment: I have the smae error `The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider`

Comment: Remove that event code and add `console.log(livello.logs.foo.args)`

Comment: thanks for reply, If I do console.log(livello.logs.foo.args); it's empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86005/discussion-between-a-k-and-monkeyuser).